# How do I add a link to a static file in an a flask/jinja HTML template?

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I am learning flask. I understand that to generate a url for a static file at `/static/style.css`, I do this `url_for('static', filename='style.css')`. I also understand that I can use a template to generate HTML, with `render_template('hello.html', name=name)` which will return the HTML output from a jinja template at `templates/hello.html`.

However, I am not sure how to return a link to a static file in a jinja template -- or if this is even how I am supposed to go about returning HTML that links to static HTML/CSS.

Basically, how do I return a link to a URL generated dynamically with python within a jinja template? This seems impossible. So what do people do? If you just put a link in the template it looks for the static file at `host/URLThatDisplaysTemplate/PathToStaticFileInTheLink` instead of `host/PathToStaticFileInTheLink`, which is what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `url_for()` in the template:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}
```

Flask adds `url_for()` to the template globals, so it is always available.